# Difference between Debug and Release when exporting C++ functions from DLL as C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I am building a DLL, which exports its functions as "C".

I am testing using a dummy function:

In my .cpp file

```
_MACRO(int) testFunction1()
{
    return 1;
}
```

In my header file

```
_MACRO(int) testFunction1();
```

This macro is defined as

```
#  define  _MACRO(ret)  extern __declspec (dllimport) ret __stdcall
#  define  _MACRO(ret)  __declspec (dllexport) ret __stdcall
```

Since I want these functions to be exported as C, i do

```
 \Debug>dumpbin /exports demo.dll
```

This correctly gives me an output of

```
 ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 000026C0 testFunction1 = testFunction1
```

But when I do the same for Release

```
\Release>dumpbin /exports demo.dll
```

I get this:

```
  1    0 00001080 testFunction1 = _get_startup_argv_mode
```

How can I make it print out the function name for release configuration? Any changes in release settings?

Comment: A DLL produced in Debug mode contains symbolic information.  A DLL produced in Release mode has reduced symbol information.  A release mode DLL may be optimized.  Reminder:  C++ may *mangle* names.

Comment: What you see from dumpbin.exe is affected by whether or not it can find the .pdb file for the dll.  In particular the "=foo" part comes from the .pdb file.  Delete the .pdb file to feel better.  I'd guess you next need to look why dumpbin.exe is so confused.  My crystal ball says it has something to do with the /debug:fastlink linker option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of COMDAT folding (merging of identical function definitions).

COMDAT folding is activated by default in Release mode (`/OPT:ICF`). To disable you can use `/OPT:NOICF`.

But why would you want to do that? It's not like it breaks your Release DLL or anything.

When you see `testFunction1 = testFunction1` the first part is the actual export name and the second part is the corresponding debug symbol.

If you link without debug symbols, you'll see just `testFunction1`, without the `=` part.